# "dereferencing type-punned pointer" error when compiling Go 1.4.2

Tags: windows, go, mingw

I'm compiling Go from source on Windows with MinGW. When running `make.bat`, I get the following error:

```
# Building C bootstrap tool.
cmd/dist
cmd/dist/windows.c: In function `errstr`:
cmd/dist/windows.c:119: warning: deferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
```

I'm not very experienced with compiling on Windows, and it appears like this issue isn't very common, as Google doesn't return anything for it specific to Go.

Edit 1: Admittedly this is a warning, not an error. However a check in the code `if errorlevel 1 goto fail` appears to consider this output an error, and stops the progress of the script.

Comment: erm... that's not an error, that's a warning ;) Is this really the reason why compilation fails?

Comment: You make a good point. That's the last line output before it reverts back to the command prompt, so execution definitely stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for Windows uses [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/), a compiler suite for 32- and 64-bit Windows based on the GNU toolchain.

For example,

```
C:\>gcc --version
gcc (tdm64-1) 4.9.2
```

Comment: Where did you get that information from? I'm using the information at the [InstallFromSource](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InstallFromSource#install-c-tools) wiki page, but it's possible this could refer to master (i.e. 1.5) rather than 1.4.2. That page says "On Windows, install gcc with MinGW"

Comment: @MalCurtis: Take another look: [InstallFromSource](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InstallFromSource#install-c-tools)